# apt commands fail because No file name for keyboard-configuration:amd64

Tags: debian, apt, dpkg

I just did an upgrade on my Debian install.

After updating my sources.list from Jessie to Stretch I did an `apt-get update`, `apt-get upgrade`  and `apt-get dist-upgrade`.

While some packages failed to update the machine is still in a usable state. However 33 have failed to install properly starting with `xserver-xorg-core`.

It fails with the following message:

> Setting up keyboard-configuration (1.164) ...
>
> /var/lib/dpkg/info/keyboard-configuration.config: 5:
>
> /etc/default/keyboard: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
>
> dpkg: error processing package keyboard-configuration (--configure):
>
> subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit
>
> status 2 dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of
>
> xserver-xorg-core: xserver-xorg-core depends on
>   keyboard-configuration; however: Package keyboard-configuration is not
>   configured yet.

Doing a `apt-get install --reinstall keyboard-configuration` returns the following message:

> E: Internal Error, No file name for keyboard-configuration:amd64

Here is the output of `uname -a`:

> Linux debian 4.9.0-6-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.82-1+deb9u3 (2018-03-02) x86_64 GNU/Linux

EDIT:

Here is the content of `/etc/default/keyboard`:

> XKBLAYOUT=us,ca XKBVARIANT=, BACKSPACE=guess XKBOPTIONS=caps:escape"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message

```
/var/lib/dpkg/info/keyboard-configuration.config: 5:
/etc/default/keyboard: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
```

suggests there’s a problem with your `/etc/default/keyboard` file. Looking at the contents shows that you have an extraneous quote at the end of `XKBOPTIONS`; remove that and everything should work again (after a `dpkg-reconfigure --pending`).